# Animate DropShadowEffect Color

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard, wpf-animation, coloranimation

How to animate a `DropShadowEffect's` color that has been already applied to an element with `XAML` without the need to re-apply a new `DropShadowEffect`?

I tried this:

```
    private void test()
    {
        DropShadowEffect DS_Moon = (DropShadowEffect)Application.Current.Resources["DS_Moon"];

        ColorAnimation DS_Moonlight = new ColorAnimation();
        DS_Moonlight.From = new Color()
        {
            A = (byte)1,
            R = (byte)0,
            G = (byte)0,
            B = (byte)0
        };
        DS_Moonlight.To = new Color()
        {
            A = (byte)1,
            R = (byte)255,
            G = (byte)255,
            B = (byte)255
        };

        DS_Moon.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, (AnimationTimeline)DS_Moonlight);
    }
```

But `DS_Moon` returns `Null`!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that i can do this:

```
Moon.Effect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.ColorProperty, (AnimationTimeline)DS_Moonlight);
```